# Find all clones of an object in iolanguage

Tags: prototype, clone, iolanguage

Is there a convenient way to get a list of all objects whose prototype is the given object? I'm inspecting `slotNames` on `Object` in an attempt to find a method that might do this, but I'm coming up short. It appears one could scan `Lobby`, but I thought I'd make sure I wasn't missing something more immediate.

Comment: What objects do you want to filter for it, all of your program? That appears hardly useful.

Comment: What do you need this for? May you want to overwrite `init` with something that adds new instances to a static list at your cloned object.

Comment: It's more a learning question. I can crawl the chain of prototypes, but the introspection doesn't seem to go the other way immediately. So no, there's no real-world problem to solve.

Comment: On the other hand, if you wanted to implement an environment like SmallTalk has, then this list would be useful for browsing objects.

Answer (score 3):

Naively, you could iterate `Collector allObjects` and apply a select over that. However, keep in mind that this will linearly scan all objects in the known heap, so it could take some time depending on your heap size.

```
Collector allObjects select(proto == Foo)
# list(Foo_0x7f81b2946c30)
```